# Error when converting java array to javascript array

Tags: java, jsp

I attempted to convert java array to js array. but it gives error as "k cannot be resolved to a variable".x.getrows returns  array.

```
  <% MySQLAccess x=new MySQLAccess();%>
     <% String b[]=x.getRows();%>
     var message="<%out.print(b[0]);%>"
     console.log(message)   
     var data=new Array();
         <% for(int k=0;k<b.length ;k++) %>
         <%  {%>

          var temp=<%= b[k] %>
          data[<% =k %>]=temp;    
        <%}%>
```

Comment: dont mix java and javascript like this .. i hope you're aware its really bad code.

Comment: isn't the space between the '%' char and the '=' in the line `data[<% =k %>]=temp;` an error?

Comment: I resolved it. then also same error

Answer (score 1):

@user2815407 What you are receiving in your string array? May be something like `[str1,str2,str3]`. If so you can easily convert this string array into js array.

```
var values = [];
values = //Your_string_array
//Iterate through each value
$.each(values, function( index, value ) {
   console.log(value);
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7EjT2/). This may not be optimal way to convert java to js array. Hope this will give you some idea. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I advice not to use scriplets, but here's the solution to your problem :

```
 <% String b[] = new String[]{"10", "20", "30"};%>
            var message = "<%out.print(b[0]);%>"
            console.log(message)
            var data = new Array();
            <% for(int k=0;k<b.length;k++){%>
            var temp =<%=b[k]%>
            data[<%=k%>] = temp;
            <%}%>
```

The error was just un-necessary spaces.

Answer (score 0):

My advice to fix this code: forget about it:

- you should NEVER use scriptlets in JSPs
- JS string literals need quotes around them, and escaped quotes and other escaped special chars inside
- JSON is the tool you should use.

So, in your controller, use

```
request.setAttribute("jsArray", someJsonSerializer.toJson(javaArray));
```

And in your JSP:

```
var data = ${jsArray};
```

Comment: controller means my MysqlAccess java program.

Comment: No. The controller is the controller in the Model-View-Controller architecture. Read http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=350 for example.